# How to save previous date data and move to the next date data in one sheet reference to changing a date in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I`m working on a report, that has two worksheets, on a daily basis. In sheet1 I do my work and in sheet2 is the monthly summary of the sheet1 datewise, but when I change the date in sheet1, the data in sheet2 disappears and updates it with the current date. How can I keep my previous date data saved? For example, if today is 1/1/19 and I do my work in sheet1, in the summary it will show underneath date 1/1/2019 but the next day 1/2/19 it disappears from 1/1/19 and shows the result in 1/2/19. Please help thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your question. Please edit your question and add the code or formulas you are using to update Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Before you change the date and after you complete your work on sheet 1, copy sheet 2 (leaving the normal sheet 2 where it is) to a new location either in the same workbook or a new one then select all cells on the copied sheet2, copy them, and then paste special values.

Then you should change the date in sheet1 (which apparently then clears all the cells in sheet2 according to your description).

Comment: @TauseefAhmad Would appreciate an up-vote on the answer if it is indeed solving your problem.